# Return Percentage of Matches between Array Comparison

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, bigdata

i have a mongodb repository with a lot of data and i need to search and classify data given an input.

I plan to have a server to work will handle the request and give the responses, but im not sure which algorithm, bigdata tool or even mongodb command to use.

This is an example of what i need to do.

I have this database:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        Colors: ["Green","Red","Blue","Yellow"]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        Colors: ["Green","Red","Blue"]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        Colors: ["Green","Red"]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        Colors: ["Green"]
    }
]
```

And then I have this input

```
String x = "Green Red"
```

or a JSON like

```
 { Colors: ["Green","Red"]}
```

And then it would return the Data that matches this input:

```
[
    {
        id: 4,
        Colors: ["Green"],
        Matches: 100%
    }
    {
        id: 3,
        Colors: ["Green","Red"],
        Matches: 100%
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        Colors: ["Green","Red","Blue"],
        Matches: 66%
    },
    {
        id: 1
        Colors: ["Green","Red","Blue","Yellow"],
        Matches: 50%
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, you want to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the array by the positive matches from the source input and then compare the resulting [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to the original. Techniques vary slightly between versions, but basically:

```
db.getCollection('junk').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "Matches": {
      "$trunc": {
        "$multiply": [
          { "$divide": [
            { "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$Colors",
                "as": "c",
                "cond": { "$in": [ "$$c", ["Green","Red"] ] }
              }
            }}, 
            { "$size": "$Colors" }
          ]},
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

You might be able to get away with [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) instead of using [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) as long as the comparison values and array both contain "unique" elements.

```
db.getCollection('junk').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "Matches": {
      "$trunc": {
        "$multiply": [
          { "$divide": [
            { "$size": {
                "$setIntersection": [ "$Colors", ["Green", "Red"] ] 
            }}, 
            { "$size": "$Colors" }
          ]},
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

And if you don't have [`$trunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/) or [`$floor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/floor/) you can just do the math using [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) and [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) to discard the remainder:

```
db.getCollection('junk').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "id": 1,
    "Colors": 1,
    "Matches": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "perc": {
            "$multiply": [
              { "$divide": [
                { "$size": {
                    "$setIntersection": [ "$Colors", ["Green", "Red"] ] 
                }}, 
                { "$size": "$Colors" }
              ]},
              100
            ]
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$subtract": [ "$$perc", { "$mod": [ "$$perc", 1 ] } ]      
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Generally stays the same principle though.

> "Number of matches divided by total length of array equals the percentage of matches"